# MVC: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type X, but this dictionary requires a model item of type X

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvvm

I am using EF model first and using viewmodels in MVC, I have problems with this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NKI3.Models.Question]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NKI3.ViewModels.IndexCreateViewModel]'.
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
public class IndexCreateViewModel
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Sname { get; set; }
    public string Cname {get;set;}
}
```

This is my Action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Q = db.Question.Include(a => a.SubjectType).Include(a => a.CoreValue);
    return View(Q.ToList());   
}
```

Here is my strongly typed view:

```
@model IEnumerable<NKI3.ViewModels.IndexCreateViewModel>

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            QuestionText
        </th>
        <th>
            Sname
        </th>
        <th>
            Cname
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cname)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I dont seem to find the solution for this, do I have to return my viewmodel inside the controller action index? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards!

Comment: It looks like db.Question returns NKI3.Models.Question rather than the ViewModel you show above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

See: note down below
Would it help to return Enumerable?

```
 return View(Q.AsEnumerable());
```

---

EDIT: Yeah, I know my first shot was wrong!... did not noticed that your view wants a

```
@model IEnumerable<NKI3.ViewModels.IndexCreateViewModel>
```

I agree with the others about converting to the required return value to the matching type...
or adjust the expecting type in the view...
maybe you can take advantage of mapping framworks like automapper (http://automapper.org/) to help you to solve to mapping code between domain objects and viewmodels.

it's up to you - No need for further down voting...

Comment: I tried it out and got this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[NKI3.Models.Question]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NKI3.ViewModels.IndexCreateViewModel]'.

Comment: I had to use mapping but i Didnt use automapper now it working perfectly

Comment: I forgot `@model IEnumerable<...` in the top of the view and got a similar error, and had to re-check what i had missed. Good post guys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the action should return a model of the same type declared on the first line of your view file.

Change your first line in the view file to:

```
@model IndexCreateViewModel
```

and change your action code (`Index()`) to a code that will return an object of type `IndexCreateViewModel`.

Comment: I will try this out after my lunch and I will report how it went :)

Comment: Did not work, error: You can not use a foreach statement for variables of type NKI3.ViewModels.IndexCreateViewModel because NKI3.ViewModels.IndexCreateViewModel not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator

Comment: You should change `IndexCreateViewModel` to be an IEnumerable of some other thing (say, create a new class named `Question` which will be an item in the IEnumerable)

Answer (score 0):

The type returned by

`db.Question.Include(a => a.SubjectType).Include(a => a.CoreValue);`

looks to be `IQueryable<NKI3.Models.Question>`

You need to convert that structure (your data model) to an `IEnumerable<IndexCreateViewModel>`

If there isn't already a helper in your app to transform between them then you'll need to write one.

```
IList<IndexCreateViewModel> viewmodel = new List<IndexCreateViewModel>();

foreach(NKI3.Models.Question item in Q)
{
   IndexCreateViewModel viewItem = new IndexCreateViewModel();
   // I don't know the properties of Question.
   viewItem.QuestionText = item.????;
   viewItem.CName = item.???;
   viewItem.SName =-item.???;
   viewModel.Add(viewItem);
}
return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: The problem is that Question entity only have QID and QuestionText. So ViewItem.Cname = item.Cname wont work. CoreValue and SubjectType entitys have Cname and Sname values.

Comment: I think you need to step back and see how your data model relates to your view model.