# Displaying results of a Stored Procedure in MVC View (EF 5 / MVC 4)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

### The goal

I want to display in my view the results of stored procedure.

### The problem

Entity Framework automatically imported for me a method that executes a procedure, however I'm not getting the results I expect displaying on the screen.

The imported function is:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<getProductsListForHome_Result> getProductsListForHome(Nullable<int> inOffer, Nullable<int> categoryId)
{
    var inOfferParameter = inOffer.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("inOffer", inOffer) :
        new ObjectParameter("inOffer", typeof(int));

    var categoryIdParameter = categoryId.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("categoryId", categoryId) :
        new ObjectParameter("categoryId", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<getProductsListForHome_Result>("getProductsListForHome", inOfferParameter, categoryIdParameter);
}
```

### What I have already tried

On ProductsController:

```
//
// GET: /Products/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ObjectResult<getProductsListForHome_Result> products = db.getProductsListForHome(1, 14);
    return View(products.ToList());
}
```

Using the previous code, when I access `http://myapp.com/Products/` I'm getting the following message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Models.getProductsListForHome_Result]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.bm_products]'.

**What do I have to do to resolve this?**

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the error message, you should be able to figure it out from that alone.

Comment: Hello, @DGibbs. Thank about your hint(?), but I am beginner and I still can not walk with my own feet, so I ask help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, well-written question!

This is a type-casting problem, and it looks like your answer is the accepted answer here:

[MVC: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type X, but this dictionary requires a model item of type X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392816/mvc-the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-x-but-this-dictionary)

Comment: Thank you very much — your link was very useful to me because it clarified that the view also has a stake in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your View is a strongly typed one, and it is declared as

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.bm_products>
```

However you are passing it a different type in controller, and experiencing the error.

What you can do:

1. Specify another type for the View. View itself might require some refactoring after this:

   ```
   @model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.getProductsListForHome_Result>
   ```
2. Preferable. Run some code in controller to convert collection returned from SP into something View can consume:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       ObjectResult<getProductsListForHome_Result> products = db.getProductsListForHome(1, 14);

       List<bm_products> viewProducts = products.Select(p => new bm_products{ProductName = p.Name, ProductPrice = p.Price}).ToList();

       return View(viewProducts);
   }
   ```

Comment: Whoa! Almost there! How can I set a property?

Comment: @chiefGui, edited with example of a syntax. Left hand are properties of class `bm_products`, right hand - properties of `getProductsListForHome_Result`. Check out [object initializers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) for better understanding.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Andrei! Just to ask, Entity Framework + Stored Procedures has some limitations, right? One is for custom column names, proceed? I am asking this because my procedure is getting the highest and lowest price of the table, then I make two columns (by procedure) called "minProductPrice" and "maxProductPrice" that doesn't exist on the table. And last question: the "p" variable isn't finding any property.

Comment: @chiefGui, every piece of code has its limitations. If I understand your case correctly, there is no limitation here. EF works with DB using the class model, therefore if your create a class with corresponding properties, or let EF generate one for you - you can safely use stored procedure that returns nonexistent columns.

Comment: Got it! So, how can I set as property the "min/maxProductPrice"? there is no such column in the bm_products' table.

Comment: @chiefGui, so your actual goal is not to display `bm_products` on the View, but rather show minimal and maximal product price? Then your problems start with View. First of all decide what will your View be displaying, define corresponding Model class for the View (or use something appropriate that already exists, obviously `bm_products` is not one of those), then run your procedure and convert its results into that Model.

Comment: Wow... I thought it was simpler. By the way, then I have to create a new model (ProductsModel, for example), create a method inside it to execute the procedure then send the results to the controller to convert into a view... is more or less that, right?

Comment: @chiefGui, more or less right. However you should avoid such operations in models - that is what controllers are for. Models should be simple objects to transfer data between controllers and views. Check out any tutorial for ASP.NET MVC to understand what models, views and controllers are intended to do.

Comment: Got it. Actually, I work with MVC for a long time. I used "model" as an example. What I mean is that I will have to create a new layer to work with the results of Stored Procedure — this part is right, right? This layer can be a ProductBuilder that passes to controller the information that I need.

Comment: @chiefGui, apologies, I was mislead by term model. Yes, what you suggesting should work - a separate layer that translates results from the DB to data that Presentation layer can works with.