# MVC Models suddenly stopped working on site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am the developer for an asp.net mvc site. Today, without warning, our  site suddenly stopped working.  When I checked the error logs I started to see a great deal of the following issue:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Volume', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Volume'.

This was repeated for every strongly-typed view that was being requested, even though the view was of the correct type! In  For some reason, the views stopped accepting the models passed down from the controller, even though they were of the correct type.  When I cleared the cache, it suddenly began working again, as if nothing has happened.

I cannot figure out why this would happen or what could have caused this.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: [There are a fair number of answers on SO already that probably apply to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392816/mvc-the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-x-but-this-dictionary).  Without seeing any code, we can't give any answers that will be of use to you and other people that find this question.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you have mismatched DLL versions. If your application has shared libraries, it's possible some component was compiled against an older version of a shared resource than the rest of your application. The object being passed between technically isn't the same. The fix is usually to recompile or use a [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) in your config file.

Comment: thanks erik.just to give more information, this is a asp.net web forms website, that gets compiled on first request.  We added the mvc functionality on to the existing structure (all of the models are in the default namespace).  I'm just wondering if this could have occured because the code for the models was recompiled, and had a different dll version than the views.

Comment: If you're sharing the models between the web forms and mvc parts of the application and those parts are compiled separately, it's probably this that is your problem. You might check to see if the assembly info is set to increment the version number of your library with each build. If so, set it to be a specific version number and change it only when it makes sense and see if that helps.